# Android gravity values appended by "|" : What is the difference between, say "top|left" and "left|top"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gravity

The android doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_gravity)  and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#gravity) says:

`"Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values."`

How does android process multiple gravity values like "`top|center_horizontal`"?
Is it that it first places the object at the top and then position is at central horizontally?

What is the difference between, say `"top|left"` and `"left|top"`?
Or is it that we always have to specify the vertical gravity first and then the horizontal gravity?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. Android saves flags as an int, and uses bitwise OR to add flags. So for example, say `LEFT` was defined as 1, and `TOP` as 2. Then to store both, you could save 3. In binary this makes sense, you want `01` and `10`, so you store `11`. The operation that does this trick is bitwise OR, or '|'. This operation is reflexive, so `LEFT|TOP == TOP|LEFT`.